# How to reset Lenovo Thinkpad to factory settings (lost password)

Tags: passwords, thinkpad, password-recovery, factory-defaults

Need to reset to factory settings: my Lenovo Thinkpad is locked because I cannot find my password and I don't remember my log in. Can you tell me how to reset it to factory settings?

Comment: Please do not use all caps for titles or anything else.  Ever :).  Can you [edit] your post and include exactly which password is reset - are you at the Windows login or a text based screen right at the beginning when you turn it on?

Comment: Windows password or Bios password?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the BIOS password right after you boot the Laptop you have four ways.

1. remember the password
2. send your laptop to lenovo and prove that you are the owner
3. replace the motherboard
4. change BIOS by soldering another one in place

It is a special security feature of Thinkpads that you cannot simply short a jumper and reset the BIOS by doing so. Source: [ThinkPad on German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ThinkPad).